# I want to get string using RX_interrupt in MBED

Tags: c

I’m trying to write code using MBED, but there are some problems.

The thing is that I want to get "character array".
If I send "abcde" to the MBED board, the board will get "abcde" and do something.

This is my code.

```c
#include <mbed.h>

char message[200];

void Rx_interrupt();

int i;

Serial pc(PA_2, PA_3);

int main() {
   pc.baud(115200);
   pc.attach(&Rx_interrupt, Serial::RxIrq);
   while (1) {
   }
   return 0;
}

void Rx_interrupt() {
    char a1[6] = "abcde";

    memset(message, 0, sizeof(message));
    i = 0;
    while (pc.readable()) {
        message[i] = pc.getc();
        i++;
    }

    if (!strcmp(a1, message)) {
        pc.printf(message);
    }
    else {
        pc.printf("FAIL");
    }
}
```

If I send "abcde", the board should print "abcde". This is my purpose.

But the board prints "FAIL" only one time. What should I do?

I think that there are some problems with `pc.getc()`.

Comment: Do you know what value of i it stops at and whether the trailing 0 for string termination is transmitted?

Comment: @cup's hints are valuable to think about. -- Additionally, if the board receives the first character, the interrupt is triggered. But the rest of the characters have not arrived yet. Serial transfer takes some time, with 115200 baud a character is sent in about 100µs. -- To debug you might like to send what you received.